# RewriteEngine to hide extension ?lang="xx"

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I rewrite this URL using `.htaccess`?

or just hide `?lang=es`.

```
http://website/services?lang=es
```

to:

```
http://website/services/es
```

Comment: mod rewrite http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/ it's a 4-part guide.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in a `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^services/([a-zA-Z]{2})/?$ /services?lang=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```